# Auto filling username and password

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

When someone logins to my website and saved password in browser next time when he opens my page how can the username and password form is auto filled so that user just needs to hit enter button to login.

Some websites has this auto filling but some websites need to enter email manually so that password is auto loaded.

How can I implement the first case in PHP and JavaScript? Thanks

Comment: Don't.  At least not using PHP/Javascript/cookies.  To auto-fill in the password as you are wanting to do would require you to use plain-text storage for it which is incredibly insecure and would make it easy for anyone with access to that computer to find out the user/pass combo.

Comment: Remembering usernames and passwords is something browsers should do. You should **never** put people's passwords in forms. **Ever**... in fact, *you should not even know people's passwords*!

Answer (score 2):

add `autocomplete="on"` to your form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
    <!-- some code -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may save this in cookies and have it displayed in php.

```
<input type='input' name='username' value='<?php echo $_COOKIES['username']; ?>' />
```